# Expiration of a recurring job in HangFire

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, hangfire

I have a recurring job and I want to expire it after `N` repeat.

```
   _recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate("test", () => Console.WriteLine("Recurring Job"), Cron.Yearly);
```

This will be repeated every year, but I want it to expire after 4 years.

Comment: add another job that will fire after 4 years and remove this job? you will have to remove the code after that though... Or just add the job without recurring 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate("test", () => Console.WriteLine("Recurring Job"), Cron.Yearly);
_backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => _recurringJobManager.RemoveIfExists("test"), TimeSpan.FromDays(1460));
```

Apparently there is no ability to expire, but it is possible to delete a job after `N` time